# "dnvm" command inside Package Console Manager doesn't show anything

Tags: asp.net-core, dnvm

Dnvm works in CMD but I can't use dnvm inside VS2015. why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please log a bug on https://github.com/aspnet/dnvm ?

Comment: @MortezaDalil @VictorHurdugaci have you logged the bug yet? If so, please post the link here. I had a similar experience. In my case `dnvm list` worked, until I executed `dnvm update-self`. After that the list command didnt output anything anymore.

Comment: @Domysee https://github.com/aspnet/dnvm/issues/475

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual commands are executing, however it does not output anything.

Run this in Package Manager Console and see how it updates your default alias.

> dnvm alias default 1.0.0-beta7 -r coreclr -arch x64

Until they fix the bug, you can run commands in Package Manager Console, just don't expect any output.

Comment: Using visual studio 2015 update1 and there is still no output, but confirming the commands do run and work.